# Integração (angularJS) com API de frases aleatórias

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Estou tentando usar angularJS para puxar dados da seguinte API que gera frases aleatórias: http://forismatic.com/en/api/

Segue trecho do código que estou usando:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: ' http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=json&lang=en'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       alert("Teste A!");
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
       alert("Teste B!");
});
```

No entanto, não estou obtendo nenhuma resposta (nenhum alert é executado), e muito menos consigo puxar os dados que desejo: a frase e o autor. Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre porque o servidor de api.forismatic.com requer CORS, ou que você utilize JSONP. O exemplo funcional abaixo é uma implementação do segundo tipo:

```js
var app = angular
.module("exemplo", [])
.controller("exemploController", function($scope, $http) {

  var url = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";

  $http.jsonp(url)
  .success(function(data){
console.log(data);
    $scope.quote = data;

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exemplo" ng-controller="exemploController">
  <span style='font-style:italic' ng-bind="quote.quoteText"></span> - <span ng-bind="quote.quoteAuthor"></span>
</div>
```